# JPA MappedSuperclass, Entity and OneToMany : inheritance issue

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I know there is numerous posts about these terms but I have a slightly different issue, which I think can be solved by design.

I have 3 entities :

- AbstractFileEntity
- FileEntity
- MultipageFileEntity

They are bound that way :

**AbstractFileEntity**

```
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractFileEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue
    protected UUID id;

}
```

**FileEntity**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_FILE")
public class FileEntity
    extends AbstractFileEntity
    implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_multipage_file")
    private MultipageFileEntity multipageFile;

    //annoying fields.....
}
```

**MultipageFileEntity**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_MULTIPAGE_FILE")
public class MultipageFileEntity
    extends AbstractFileEntity
    implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "multipageFile", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private Map<Integer, FileEntity> files;

}
```

So here my Multipage is just basically a collection of File. But I need them to fit in the same Object family because they can be stored into a Collection object.

**Problems**:

1. When I use `@MappedSuperclass` I fall into the *Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class:* error.
2. When I use on the Abstract class, the `@Entity` & the `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)` annots, I have a reference id loop, because in the same table we have a collection of itself -> infinite collections of itselfs.
3. When I use the TABLE_PER_CLASS strategy, I basically need to replicate all fields

I will probably just make one Entity File, and add on page number and a MultipageFile Id to it and differenciate a Simple File and a Multipage File with these; that's all.

Any insights on this ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: Actually, I'm using the TABLE_PER_CLASS strategy and I not all the fields need to be replicated in the 2 child tables. It seems to be the good way to go, I'll dig this too see if my features still working properly. But still, I don't understand the goal of the MappedSuperclass annotation :(

Comment: A `@MappedSuperclass` is simply a way to define attributes that are only applicable to the subclasses that inherit it since no table is associated to a `@MappedSuperclass` type.

Comment: Ok I tryed to use it the wrong way. I made it an abstract class to generify 2 childs objects. Then I passed a List of this abstract superclass as an attribute of one child. So, here it needed to be able to map an entity and that's why I didn't need this annotation finally.